# Is there a name for the relation between Menger Sponge and Vicsek Fractal?

Tags: terminology, fractals

Both the Menger Sponge and the Vicsek Fractal in 3D can be constructed by starting with a cube, dividing it into 27 smaller cubes (3x3x3 grid), removing some of these cubes, and then applying the process recursively for each smaller cube.

In the case of Menger Sponge, 20 cubes are left and 7 are removed: the central cube and the cubes at the centers of each of the 6 faces. In the case of 3D Vicsek fractal, the 7 cubes forming a kind of 3D cross are left and the other 20 removed. So in a single iteration, the cubes removed in one fractal are those which are left in the other. One could say that the unit cell of one fractal is the complement of the cube and the unit cell of the other fractal.

Is there a name for this kind of relation between two fractals? Of course, the whole fractals are not complements of each other, only their unit cells are.

Answer (score 2):

*Since this is not an answer but really just a too-long comment, I've made it CW to avoid rep gain:*

I don't think there is any existing snappy terminology for this, but [iterated function systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) provide a nice way of describing what's going at a more general level:

Let $\mathscr{H}^n$ be the space of compact nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Hausdorff metric. Every finite set of contraction maps $F=\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ yields a single contraction map on $\mathscr{H}$, namely $$\hat{F}: X\mapsto \bigcup_{1\le i\le n}f_i[X].$$ Since $\mathscr{H}$ is complete, by [Banach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) $\hat{F}$ has a unique fixed point $S_F$. The relevance of this is that many (most?) naturally-occurring "self-similar" fractals can be described in such a way; for example, the Cantor set is $S_{t_1,t_2}$ for the pair of orientation-preserving affine maps $t_1,t_2:\mathbb{R}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^1$ which respectively map $[0,1]$ to $[0,{1\over 3}]$ and $[{2\over 3}, 1]$. Similarly, the Menger sponge is $S_F$ for a particular set of $20$ maps $F$, corresponding to the $20$ "retained" cubes in the construction. Note that we may have $S_F=S_G$ even if $F\not=G$ (e.g. take $G=F^2$); moreover, Banach's fixed point theorem also tells us that we can get to $S_F$ from *any* point in $\mathscr{H}^n$ by applying $F$ repeatedly.

This all sets up the following definition (letting $\mathscr{F}^n$ be the subspace of $\mathscr{H}^n$ consisting of sets of the form $S_F$ for some $F$ as above):

> Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Say that $A,B\in\mathscr{F}^n$ are *stagewise-complementary* iff there are finite sets of contraction maps $F,G$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a nonempty compact set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with $dim(X)=n$ such that $$A=S_F, B=S_G,F[X]\cup G[X]=X,\mbox{ and }dim(F[X]\cap G[X])<n.$$ In this case write $A\perp B$.

The intersection-dimension condition basically says that $F[X]$ and $G[X]$ are "as disjoint as they could be" - we generally won't be able to avoid overlap on boundaries, but we can ask that there not be any "substantial" overlapping.

Note that from $\perp$ we get an equivalence relation generated by "shared complements" - let $A\sim B$ iff there is an even-length sequence $C_1,C_2,...,C_{2k-1}, C_{2k}\in\mathscr{F}^n$ with $C_1=A$, $C_{2k}=B$, and $C_i\perp C_{i+1}$ for each $1\le i<2k$. Equivalence relations are a bit easier/more compelling to think about than "complementarity" relations, in my opinion, so here's a question I embarrassingly can't see how to answer:

> How many classes does $\sim$ partition $\mathscr{F}^n$ into?

"Obviously" the answer is continuum-many ... right? At the moment, though, I can't even show that the answer is $>1$! (I've gone ahead and asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689792/counting-fractals-via-stagewise-complements).)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the lack of response to this we can probably take this opportunity to define the terminology.

We can define an "inner cross" of an $n$ dimensional hypercube as the $2n$ face centered cubes and the central cube of a $3^n$ decomposition of the hypercube.

The Vicsek Fractal of a hypercube then is the fractal generated by taking the hyper cube, identifying its $3^n$ decomposition deleting everything but its inner cross and then recursively computing the Vicsek Fractal for each of the remaining cubes in the remaining inner cross.

The Menger Sponge of a hypercube then has the definition of taking a hypercube, identify its $3^n$ decomposition, deleting the inner cross and then recursively applying this procedure to all the constituent cubes.

I think this terminology feels clean and consistent and very clearly articulates that "complimentary" relationship you were hinting at.